# How to create SQLite DB on onCreate method in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem creating a DB. Here is the part of the code:

```
public class DBAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHELPER;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_Name = "DB.db";

    //*****KONSTRUKTION DB**************************************************************************
    //*****ERSTE TABELLE: Konfiguration*************************************************************
    public static final String TABLE_Name_Konf          =       "TB_Konfig";
    public static final String KEY                      =       "id";
    public static final int KEY_Spalte                  =       0;
    public static final String SENSORSERIENNUMMER       =       "Sensornummer";
    public static final int SENSORSERIENNUMMER_SPALTE   =       1;
    public static final String[] SPALTENKonf            =       new String[]{KEY,SENSORSERIENNUMMER};

    //*****SENSOR TABELLEN**************************************************************************
    // Sting KEY kann von Konfiguration verwendet werden
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_SENS  =       "Sensor";
    public static String SENSORNUMMER;
    public static final String TIMESTAMP        =       "TimeStamp(Unix)";
    public static final String MESSWERT_Temp    =       "Temperatur";
    public static final String MESSWERT_DRUCK   =       "Druck";
    public static final String MESSWERT_FEUCHTE =       "Feuchte";
    public static final int TIMESTAMP_SPALTE    =       1;
    public static final int TEMP_SPALTE         =       2;
    public static final int DRUCK_SPALTE        =       3;
    public static final int FEUCHTE_SPALTE      =       4;
    public static final String[]  SPALTENSensor =       new String[] {KEY,TIMESTAMP,MESSWERT_Temp,MESSWERT_DRUCK,MESSWERT_FEUCHTE};




    public static final String SQL_CREATE_Konf  =       "create table "
                                                        + TABLE_Name_Konf + " ("
                                                        + KEY + " integer primary key autoincrement, " // SQL -> int
                                                        + SENSORSERIENNUMMER + " integer not null"
                                                        + ")";

    public static final String SQL_CREATE_SENS  =       "create table "
                                                        + TABLE_NAME_SENS + " ("
                                                        + KEY + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                                                        + TIMESTAMP + " text not null,"    // SQL -> String
                                                        + MESSWERT_Temp + " real not null,"
                                                        + MESSWERT_DRUCK + " real not null,"
                                                        + MESSWERT_FEUCHTE + " real not null"
                                                        + ")";
```

Hier is the DBHelper with the onCreate:

```
 private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "DB erstellt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SENS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }
    }
```

The Problem is, that everytime the onCreate is called I get a SynthaxError. I managed to get the source of the problem. I can create the db everytime the 
+ TIMESTAMP + " text not null," is set as a comment. So this must be the source of the problem, but honestly I don't get why. 
If I give the SQL_CREATE_Konf into the onCreate this db is created well. 
Why is this not working with SQL_CREATE_SENS?

Comment: Do you have all these columns in your DB? what did you mean by "I can create the db everytime the + TIMESTAMP + " text not null," is set as a comment"

Comment: Yes i have all these columns in the DB. What i meant was: when i try to create the DB  (SQL_CREATE_Sens) without this line it works. So I assume this line must be the source of the problems.

Comment: What error are you getting in logcat?

Comment: Can you try renaming "TimeStamp(Unix)"  to TimeStamp_Unix something like this.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your statement bellow

```
  public static final String SQL_CREATE_SENS  =       "create table "
                                                    + TABLE_NAME_SENS + " ("
                                                    + KEY + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                                                    + TIMESTAMP + " text not null,"    // SQL -> String
                                                    + MESSWERT_Temp + " real not null,"
                                                    + MESSWERT_DRUCK + " real not null,"
                                                    + MESSWERT_FEUCHTE + " real not null"
                                                    + ")";
```

is the value for TIMESTAMP here `public static final String TIMESTAMP        =       "TimeStamp(Unix)";`

That is not a valid column name. Get a good descriptive column like

```
public static final String TIMESTAMP        =       "TimeStamp_Unix";
```

then you can keep any value for your time stamp when need arise. So the problem is the the column name, what you have looks like a function that generates a time stamp.
Refer to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) documentation for details on how to set a default value if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String TIMESTAMP        =       "TimeStamp(Unix)"
```

You cannot have () parentheses in column names (without quoting the name). Rename the column.